# SQL or PL/SQL queries to Print sequence of given N numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help in building the query as the below structured.i have tried using for loop but its just printing as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
For example if the N Value is 9 means the output should be like this. 

**EXAMPLE Output** :

0
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0

Comment: "print" as in dbms_output?

Comment: ya dbms_output or rows anything is fine @wolφi

Comment: Nope not a homework. just a logical question asked by my colleague or is there any special functions to write this @WBAR

Comment: I have tried using for loop and also Connect by. But i cannot get the exact output as mentioned above.  @EvilTeach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This select query gives exact result:

```
WITH CTE1 AS 
(SELECT 9 AS COL FROM DUAL)
,CTE2
AS (    
SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS A,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(LEVEL - 1, ' ') AS B,
COL
FROM DUAL, CTE1
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= COL + 1)
SELECT B
FROM (SELECT A, B FROM CTE2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 * COL - A, B
FROM CTE2
WHERE A != COL)
ORDER BY A;
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
 0
 0 1
 0 1 2
 0 1 2 3
 0 1 2 3 4
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 0 1 2 3 4
 0 1 2 3
 0 1 2
 0 1
 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this just in SQL - albeit with a bind variable if you want to be able to specify `n` - you need to combine start with the `connect by` and build from there. This is one way, though I'm pretty sure it can be done without the `union`:

```
with t as (
  select level as rn, level - 1 as val
  from dual
  connect by level <= :n + 1
)
select t1.rn as rn,
  listagg(t2.val, ' ') within group (order by t2.val) as answer
from t t1
join t t2 on t2.val <= t1.val
group by t1.rn, t1.val
union all
select (2 * (:n + 1)) - t1.rn,
  listagg(t2.val, ' ') within group (order by t2.val) as answer
from t t1
join t t2 on t2.val <= t1.val
where t1.rn <= :n
group by t1.rn, t1.val
order by rn;
```

The CTE generates the numbers 0 to n. The two halves of the union create the mirror halves of the output; the second has the `rn <= :n` filter to prevent the 'middle' line being duplicated.

With:

```
var n number;
exec :n := 9;
```

This gives:

```
    RN ANSWER                                 
------ ----------------------------------------
     1 0                                        
     2 0 1                                      
     3 0 1 2                                    
     4 0 1 2 3                                  
     5 0 1 2 3 4                                
     6 0 1 2 3 4 5                              
     7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6                            
     8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7                          
     9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8                        
    10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                      
    11 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8                        
    12 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7                          
    13 0 1 2 3 4 5 6                            
    14 0 1 2 3 4 5                              
    15 0 1 2 3 4                                
    16 0 1 2 3                                  
    17 0 1 2                                    
    18 0 1                                      
    19 0
```

Or for 6:

exec :n := 6;

```
    RN ANSWER                                 
------ ----------------------------------------
     1 0                                        
     2 0 1                                      
     3 0 1 2                                    
     4 0 1 2 3                                  
     5 0 1 2 3 4                                
     6 0 1 2 3 4 5                              
     7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6                            
     8 0 1 2 3 4 5                              
     9 0 1 2 3 4                                
    10 0 1 2 3                                  
    11 0 1 2                                    
    12 0 1                                      
    13 0
```

You don't really want to see the `rn` but you can remove that by putting this in a subquery.

Comment: +1 for Alex Poole..But its not working in R12 Database.. The Below Query from Nishanthi Grashia looks fine. Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1):

Using a while loop:

```
DECLARE
  my_limit SIMPLE_INTEGER := 9;
  my_step  SIMPLE_INTEGER := +1;
  i SIMPLE_INTEGER := 0;
  s VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  WHILE (i > -1) LOOP
    s := '';
    FOR j IN 0 .. i LOOP
      IF j>0 THEN s := s || ' '; END IF;
      s := s || to_char(j);
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(s);

    IF (i >= my_limit) THEN my_step := -1; END IF;
    i := i + my_step;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, that **sys_connect_by_path** is what you are looking for.

[Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions183.htm#SQLRF06116)

SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH is valid only in hierarchical queries. It returns the path of a column value from root to node, with column values separated by char for each row returned by CONNECT BY condition.

```
with desired_number as (select 5 as nm from dual)
,tree
 as (    select level - 1 as a, sys_connect_by_path(level - 1, ' ') as b, nm
           from dual, desired_number
     connect by level <= nm + 1)
select *
from (select a, b from tree
      union all
      select 2 * nm - a, b
        from tree
       where a != nm)
order by a
```

Btw, how do you format it like sql?

Answer (score 0):

You may find **connect by** to be a useful basis for working out the answer.

```
select level n
from dual
connect by level <= 10
```

Comment: I have tried this. But the output was coming as  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

Answer (score 0):

Using three nested for loops:

```
DECLARE
  my_limit SIMPLE_INTEGER := 9;

  PROCEDURE one_line(n simple_integer) IS
    s VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    FOR j IN 0 .. n LOOP
      IF j>0 THEN s := s || ' '; END IF;    
      s := s || to_char(j);
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(s);
  END one_line;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 0 .. my_limit LOOP
    one_line(i);
  END LOOP;
  FOR i IN REVERSE 0 .. my_limit-1 LOOP
    one_line(i);
  END LOOP;  
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it at last:

```
  WITH CTE AS
  (
        SELECT LEVEL-1 COL
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
  )

  SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(COL, ' ') COL  
  FROM ( SELECT COL,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COL) RN
         FROM CTE) 
      START WITH RN = 1 
      CONNECT BY PRIOR RN = RN - 1 
  UNION ALL

  SELECT COL FROM( 
      SELECT  RPAD(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(COL, ' ') , '20'  )COL 
      FROM ( SELECT COL,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COL) RN
              FROM CTE)
      START WITH RN = 1 
      CONNECT BY PRIOR RN = (RN - 1 )
      ORDER BY COL DESC
  );
```

Produces This output:

```
0
 0 1
 0 1 2
 0 1 2 3
 0 1 2 3 4
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6      
 0 1 2 3 4 5        
 0 1 2 3 4          
 0 1 2 3            
 0 1 2              
 0 1                
 0
```